# Print substring of column in awk based on filter

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a string as follows which is comma separated

```
2019-08-3123:10:38,abcd:343:334334,v1-customer,{Ad=299:ADT=1}:{ADpif=10:DDI=299},abd-fed,568:3433
```

I need to have all the string but only substring of 4th column on filter ":", so the output should be as follows

```
2019-08-3123:10:38,abcd:343:334334,v1-customer,{ADpif=10:DDI=299},abd-fed,568:3433
```

I tried using substring, but it needs starting index which is not fixed, so unable to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: If the separator in column 4 is `:`, do you always want to remove the first element? Can column 4 consist of further elements, for example `{Ad=299:ADT=1}:{ADpif=10:DDI=299}:{ADA=1:XY=42}:{Adx=2:FOO=21}`?

Comment: What have your tried to do to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the column, trim the specific column (4th column) and join them together again. The AWK syntax is a bit convoluted

```
echo 'aaaa,b1234,cccc' | awk  -F, -v OFS=, '{ $2=substr($2,2,2); print $0 }'
```

Prints

```
aaaa,12,cccc
```

The `-F` sets the input field seperator to the comma and the `-v OFS=,` sets the output field separator to a comma. `$0` refers to the entire line, while `$2` refers to the second field. It turns out that the `$<n>` variables are mutable so you can mutate `$2` and then print the entire line using `$0`.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to trim based on digits, rather I want to trim based on another filter, how can I do that?

Comment: You should investigate awk's `match()` function. Use it to extract what you want from the 4th column.

Answer (score 0):

```
may be this way:


    BEGIN {
        FS=","
        OFS=","
    }

    {
    #    print $0
    # Split 4-th column by "}:{"
        k=split($4,A,"}:{")
    # The result of split is in array A, k is the array size
    # Now gather splitted columns again into $4, omitting first one    
        $4="{" A[2]
        for (i=3;i<=k;i++) $4=$4 "}:{" A[k]
        print $0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your goal, but it appears to be for the 4th field you want to change the existing field from/to:

```
{Ad=299:ADT=1}:{ADpif=10:DDI=299}

{ADpif=10:DDI=299}
```

leaving the remainder of fields unchanged. If that is your goal, it can be handled fairly easily with the `sub` command, e.g.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=',' '$4 == $4 {sub (/^.*}:/, "", $4)}1' file
```

Above simply locates the 4th field and substitutes what matches the regular-expression `/^.*}:/` (from begining of field through the closing `'}'` followed by a `':'`, leaving the remainder of the field.

**Example Use/Output**

Testing with your example input produces the following:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=',' '$4 == $4 {sub (/^.*}:/, "", $4)}1' file
2019-08-3123:10:38,abcd:343:334334,v1-customer,{ADpif=10:DDI=299},abd-fed,568:3433
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^,]*/\n&/4;s/\n[^}]*}://' file
```

Insert a unique delimiter (in this case a `\n`) in front of the 4th field and use it to pattern match the string to be deleted.